# How can I resolve "HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., 401" error?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, http-error

**The problem:**
I'm trying to read in a .gz JSON file that is stored in one of my project's cloud storage bucket using a google colab python notebook and I keep getting this error:

```
HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., 401
```

**My code:**

```
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')
with fs.open('bucket/path.json.gz') as f:
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) 
    file_as_string = gz.read()
    json_a = json.loads(file_as_string)
```

**I've tried all of these authentication methods and still get the same 401 error :**

```
!gcloud auth login
!gcloud auth list
!gcloud projects list
!gcloud config set project 'myproject-id'
```

---

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

---

```
!gcloud config set account 'my GCP email'
```

---

```
!gcloud auth activate-service-account
```

---

```
!gcloud auth application-default login
```

---

```
!gsutil config
```

---

```
!gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false
```

---

```
!gsutil config -a
```

**I've also set my GCP IAM permissions to:**

- Editor
- Owner
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer
- Storage Transfer Admin

Comment: Start with **gcloud init**, then **gcloud auth application-default login**. If that does not work show the commands and the results in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from your question but:

1. `gcloud` and Google SDKs both use Google's identity|auth platform **but** they don't share state. You usually (!) can't login using `gcloud` and expect code using an SDK to be authenticated too
2. @john-hanley correctly points out that one (often confusing) way to share state between `gcloud` and code using Google SDKs is to use `gcloud auth application-default login`. However, this only works because `gcloud` writes its state locally and code using Google SDKs when running as the same user on the same host, will be able to access this state. I think (!?) this won't work with browser-based collab
3. I'm unfamiliar with `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem` but, it is **not** a Google SDK. Unless its developers have been particularly thoughtful, it won't be able to leverage authentication done by the Google SDK using `auth.authenticate_user()`.

So...

I think you should:

1. Ensure that your user account (`you@gmail.com` or whatever) has `roles/storage.objectAdmin` (or any [predefined role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) that permits `storage.objects.get`).
2. Use `google.collab.auth` and `auth.authenticate_user()` to obtain credentials for the browser's logged-in user (i.e. `you@gmail.com`).
3. Use a Google Cloud Storage library, e.g. [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) to access the GCS object. The Google library **can** leverage the credentials obtained in the previous step.

##### Update

Here's an [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/indranildchandra/ML101-Codelabs/blob/master/src/Colaboratory_Dataset_Interactions_Examples.ipynb#scrollTo=s6nDq8Nk7aPN).

**NOTE**: it use the API Client Library rather than the Cloud Client Library but these are functionally equivalent.